# Prove $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, matrix-rank

I am given the info that A is an invertible  m by m matrix and B is a m by n matrix. By solving for the null space $ABx=0$, I get $A^{-1}ABx=A^{-1}0$, therefore $Bx=0$. I concluded that the null spaces of A and AB must be equivalent, and therefore the nullity(AB) = nullity(B) = some number p. Therefore rank(AB) = n-p = rank(B)   (because both AB and B are m by n matrices).   Is this proof valid, specifically the null space step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is incomplete.  You've essentially justified $\text{Null}(AB) \subseteq \text{Null}(B)$, but you haven't proven the reverse containment $\text{Null}(B) \subseteq \text{Null}(AB)$. If $Bx = 0$, then $ABx = A0 = 0$. Hence $x \in \text{Null}(B)$ $\implies$ $x \in \text{Null}(AB)$. Thus $\text{Null}(B) \subseteq \text{Null}(AB)$, and given that you justified  $\text{Null}(AB) \subseteq \text{Null}(B)$, consequently we have  $\text{Null}(AB) = \text{Null}(B)$. So $\text{dim}\, \text{Null}(AB) = \text{dim}\, \text{Null}(B)$, i.e., $\text{rank}(AB) = \text{rank}(B)$.

Comment: there was a slight typo, I forgot an A in the nullspace equation. I fixed it, but that method is still invalid, right?

Comment: It's incomplete. You've essentially justified $\text{Null}(AB) \subseteq \text{Null}(B)$, but you haven't proven the reverse containment $\text{Null}(B) \subseteq \text{Null}(AB)$.

Comment: So I just have to prove it the opposite way, starting with Bx=0 and then I should be fine?

Comment: If you follow my answer, you'll see that after proving the reverse containment, we have $\text{Null}(AB) = \text{Null}(B)$. Then by taking dimensions, we deduce $\text{rank}(AB) = \text{rank}(B)$.

Comment: Ya ok it was just the reverse containment that I wasn't sure of, I know how to use the dimensions and properties of matrices to prove the rest